# ACM ICPC Programming competition problem

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you answer this 2009 ACM International Collegiate Programming Contest Finals problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842587/can-you-answer-this-2009-acm-international-collegiate-programming-contest-finals)

Hi,

I am attempting to do question 1 here-> http://cm.baylor.edu/ICPCWiki/attach/Problem%20Resources/2009WorldFinalProblemSet.pdf

and cannot really come up with a good algorithm to solve it :

Basically, there are n planes, n is read in from standard input. There are then n intervals for times in which the planes can arrive, you must compute the largest interval between all planes that is possible. So, say

```
n = 3
```

and you are given the inputs

```
0 10
5 15
10 15
```

The answer is : 7: 30, the largest possible interval between planes.

Not really sure how I would go about solving this. Any tips ?

Comment: The point of a programming contest is to test your programming skills, not your question asking skills…

Comment: So helpful, Andrew, thank you :) I assume you realise this question is two years old and I am merely posting a question I am struggling with to study for a future competition, yes?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842587/can-you-answer-this-2009-acm-international-collegiate-programming-contest-finals

Comment: Those solutions are quite hard to make sense of.

Comment: If you don't understand the existing solutions, I don't like your chances of coming up with a better one, or even a 'good' one.

Answer (score 1):

For the first plane, select the earliest possible arrival time
For the last plane, select the latest possible arrival time

For elements 2 through element n-1:

Search for a midpoint plane by dividing the range between element 1 and element n
   (Hopefully, that will be close to the element n/2)

recursivly call the same function for element 1 and the midpoint element
   recursivly call the same function for the element after the midpoint element and element n

That will evenly divide up the time available within the constraints of the planes scheduled windows.

Once you have roughly evenly spaced windows, select the smallest window and test it with its neighboring planes to see if they can shift some to expand the smallest window.  Repeat this process until the smallest window can't shift a significent amount.